# ExtJs 3. Display calendar by clicking on text field

Tags: calendar, extjs3

how to show a calendar when you click on text field icon on the left of the calendar?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'render' event to listen to clicks on the datefield, then use the onTriggerClick() function to expand the date picker:

```
       {
            xtype:'datefield',
            name:'date1',
            fieldLabel:'Date',
            listeners:{
                render:function (d) {
                    d.el.on('click', function () {
                        d.onTriggerClick();
                    });

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 {
xtype:'datefield', 
fieldLabel:'Start Date', 
name:'start_date',
dataIndex:'start_date'
}

use the items[] for the field container and put above lines for datefield in items and call it
```

Answer (score 0):

Alin Suciu's answer is not enough for extjs 5.
Because when click datepicker image, picker does not trigger.
So i changed it a little. 
it's not best way but working.

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function (d) {
        d.getEl().on('click', function (e, t, o) {
            if (e.target.id.indexOf('picker') <= 0) {
                d.onTriggerClick();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

if there is any better solution advice, i will change my code. 
Best regards.